# mvn clean install of https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java hanging forever

Tags: java-8, graphviz, j2v8

I downloaded code from https://github.com/nidi3/graphviz-java and ran

'mvn clean install'.

It is stuck after this output

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ graphviz-java ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to D:\graphviz-java-master\target\test-classes

my java setting is :
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0

Comment: The mentioned library seems to rely on J2v8 and Nashorn as its fallback. Do you have at least one of these setup properly? According to [this blogpost](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2144908/scripting-jvm-languages/nashorn--javascript-made-great-in-java-8.html), the Nashorn JS engine might not be automatically available.

Comment: not sure how to enable nashorn through maven

Comment: In the blogpost I was referring to, they just added the Nashorn command line tools to the PATH. (Not sure whether that's actually required for the GitHub project in question). Might be easier to just install J2V8. The main problem here is that you don't have an error message we could help you with. You might have to contact the project's maintainer directly for more detailed setup instructions.